# Eliminar un registro concreto de una LinkedList y con bucle foreach

Tags: java, lista, poo, arraylist, class

He creado el siguiente método para eliminar un registro en una LinkedList.

```
public boolean eliminarCuenta(String ibanEliminar){
    boolean operacionRealizada = false;
    
    for (CuentaBancaria lista: listaClientes){
        if (lista.getIbanCliente().equalsIgnoreCase(ibanEliminar)){
            if (lista.getSaldoCuenta() == 0){
                listaClientes.remove();
                operacionRealizada = true;
                break;
            } else {
                operacionRealizada = false;
            }
        } else{
            operacionRealizada = false;
        }
    }
    
    return operacionRealizada;
}
```

El método busca el registro y si tiene saldo cero elimina el registro, pero al ejecutarlo si la cuenta que busco es saldo cero me elimina SIEMPRE el primer registro de la LinkedList aunque el Iban a buscar sea diferente.
Se que en la sentencia listaClientes.remove() tengo que pasarle el índice del elemento a eliminar, pero en un bucle for normal, se que le puedo pasar i, pero, ¿cómo se lo paso en un bucle foreach? ¿cómo obtengo el índice del registro que coincide con el iban a eliminar?

Un saludo.

Comment: Ademas de usar el indice ,puedes usar `remove` con el dato particular que quieres eliminar..`listaClientes.remove(lista);` donde lista sera el objeto cuyo `ibacliente` coincide con `ibanaeliminar` y cuyo saldo es 0

Comment: y como sabes cual se va a eliminar? cumple alguna condicion?

Comment: @Dramaturgo Gracias!!! Porque (lista) es en el registro que se encuentra actualmente cuando se cumple la condición

Comment: @Pozo correcto,un detalle adicional ambas condicionales pueden ser aplicadas en conjunto con el operador lógico AND `if (lista.getIbanCliente().equalsIgnoreCase(ibanEliminar) && lista.getSaldoCuenta() == 0)` ,si declaraste el valor de `operacionRealizada` como `false` no es necesario el uso de `else` por que si no se cumplen las condicionales el valor que regresara tu método es el valor de la variable osea `false`,saludos

Comment: @Dramaturgo Ok, muchas gracias por los detalles, me he fijado que he cometido esos errores en más métodos! :(